# Atualizar parte de página web com Electron. (Alterar somente conteúdo e manter header, footer e menu fixo)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

Estou fazendo uma aplicação utilizando o Electron, dividi a tela em header, footer, menu e conteúdo como se faz em uma aplicação web comum.

[image: O problema são os botões de minimizar, maximizar e fechar.]

Os botões precisam realizar as ações na janela principal do Electron mas não está funcionando e não sei como resolver.

Existe outro jeito de dividir esta tela pra que que somente uma área seja atualizada ou então como redirecionar o usuário para outra página no Electron? (Ficar mudando o conteúdo da página principal. Sei que é possível pois já vi até jogos desenvolvidos em Electron)

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./photon/css/photon.min.css">

    <script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jQuery');
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#header").load("header.html");
            $("#footer").load("footer.html");
            $("#menu").load("menu.html");
            $("#conteudo").load("conteudo.html");
        });
    </script>

    <script src="./controller.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="window">
        <div id="header"></div>

        <div class="window-content">
            <div class="pane-group">
                <div id="menu"></div>
                <div id="conteudo"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>


    <script>
        // You can also require other files to run in this process
        require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

header.html

```
    <header class="toolbar toolbar-header">
        <h1 class="title">Integração</h1>

        <div class="toolbar-actions">

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-home"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-folder"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default active">
                    <span class="icon icon-cloud"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-popup"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-shuffle"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="icon icon-home icon-text"></span> Filters
            </button>

            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <button id="btnMinimizar" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-minus"></span>
                </button>
                <button id="btnMaximizar" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-window"></span>
                </button>
                <button id="btnFechar" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="icon icon-cancel"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>
```

controller.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        const app = require('electron').remote.app;
        const {
            remote
        } = require('electron');

        $('#btnFechar').click(function () {
            console.log("Fechar");
            remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().close();

        });

        $('#btnMinimizar').click(function () {
            console.log("Minimizar");
            remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().minimize();

        });

        $('#btnMaximizar').click(function () {
            console.log("Maximizar");
            if (remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().isMAximized()) {
                remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().restore();
            } else {
                remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().maximize();
            }

        });

    });
```

---

**Atualização 01:** Resolvi a questão dos botões. Era um problema muito simples eu só tinha esquecido de chamar o script do controller.js no arquivo onde eles foram definidos.

A dúvida agora é somente uma: **Como fazer para atualizar somente a parte do conteúdo como em uma página web normal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito interessante a pergunta!

Há uma ideia de como faze-lo nesta página: 
[Link para W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing_view1)

Comment: Agradeço imensamente pela ajuda e pela disponibilidade. Sua resposta ajudou muito.